# Apply libcst codemod and skip test files

Tags: python, libcst

I am writing a [codemod with libcst](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/codemods_tutorial.html) which inherits from `VisitorBasedCodemodCommand`. It works fine but is rather slow. One simple trick would be to skip all test files which start with `test_` by convention. However I haven't been able to find a place to add such logic in my codemod.

I saw a [`SkipFile` exception](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/codemods.html#libcst.codemod.SkipFile) but I don't know from where I could trigger it.

How can I ignore my test files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise `SkipFile` anywhere in the codemod when you detect that the current file can not be modified by the codemod. Since you know upfront you want to skip the test files completely, you can bail out on module node visit already, for example:

```
import pathlib
import libcst as cst
from libcst.codemod import VisitorBasedCodemodCommand, SkipFile


class SkipTests(VisitorBasedCodemodCommand):
    def visit_Module(self, mod: cst.Module) -> bool | None:
        if pathlib.Path(self.context.filename).name.startswith("test_"):
            raise SkipFile("not touching any tests")
        return True
```

Now, when you invoke `libcst.tool` with the codemod, you should see a log line for each skipped file:

```
$ python -m libcst.tool codemod so.SkipTests .
Calculating full-repo metadata...
Executing codemod...
Codemodding /path/to/example/test_mod.py
Skipped codemodding /path/to/example/test_mod.py: not touching any tests

Finished codemodding 8 files!
 - Transformed 7 files successfully.
 - Skipped 1 files.
 - Failed to codemod 0 files.
 - 0 warnings were generated.
```